# How to get user's elements from list and return it in .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

My idea is to get user's liked books from list. User entity has list of type `Book`, but I want to return list of type `BookDto` from it.

When I hit my endpoint in Postman, I am getting status 200OK and empty list `[]` <-- like that, however I know user has something in this list already so there is no possibility that there are 0 elements. I did repository pattern and controller for that. I did also some coding. I am using .NET 5 and Entity Framework. I did also some debugging and user is not null, it has correct value. Any suggestions?

```
[HttpGet("GetUserFavorites")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<BookDto>>> GetUserLikedBooks()
{
    var username = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

    return await _likeRepository.GetUserFavoriteBooks(username);
}

public async Task<List<BookDto>> GetUserFavoriteBooks(string username)
{
    var user = await _userRepo.GetUserByUsername(username);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Something gone wrong, try again.");
    }

    user.LikedBooks ??= new List<Book>();
        
    var bookDtos = user.LikedBooks.Select(x => new BookDto
            {
                Title = x.Title,
                Author = x.Author,
                PublicationYear = x.PublicationYear,
                Description = x.Description,
                Count = x.Count
            })
            .ToList();

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return bookDtos;
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<Book> LikedBooks { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int PublicationYear { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class BookDto
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int PublicationYear { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When you debug, is this setting `LikedBooks` to an empty list?: `user.LikedBooks ??= new List<Book>();`  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: can you show the `GetUserByUsername`() function code ? you propably do not use `.Include(u=>u.LikedBooks )`

Comment: @gepa ye, I didn't use it. Now it works. Thank you sir!

Comment: .NET 5 is end of life. You should consider upgrading to .NET 6/7